# Is there any single property/option for creating all borders in LaTeX table?

Tags: tables, formatting

```
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | }
  \hline                       
  1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
  4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \hline  
\end{tabular}
```

If we want to create a table with all the borders (like an MS Word table), is there a simple single option we can use in LaTex to create such table instead of typing "|" and \hline at multiple places (as shown in the above example)?

Comment: Fortunately not.

Comment: As far as I know there's nothing in standard packages. But why the hell do you want to mimic ugly typography?

Comment: On a completely unrelated matter, the documentation of package `booktabs` has some nice tips regarding the typesetting of nice tables.

Comment: Never have used ConTeXt myself I am willing to bet that it *has* this option…

Comment: On a completely related matter, the documentation of package `booktabs` has some nice tips regarding the typesetting of nice tables.  The #1 tip is that you should never use vertical lines.  The #2 tip is that you should (almost) never use double horizontal lines.  A related item to #2 is that people use way too many horizontal lines, and most tables look much nicer without them.  For this reason, there's not as much effort in TeX to make vertical and horizontal lines easier to draw.

Answer (score 1):

It’s easy peasy with `tblr` environment of the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray). You can even set hlines and vlines as default.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {ccc},
  hlines, vlines,
}                      
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tblr}

\SetTblrInner{hlines,vlines} % set default hlines and vlines

\bigskip

\begin{tblr}{ccc}      
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tblr}

\bigskip

\begin{tblr}{lcr}      
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have the key `hvlines` which draws all the rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines]
  1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
  4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]